# Rails 4 .order() gets mangled with JOINS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm working on upgrading an existing Rails 3.2 application to 4.0.  I've run into a brick wall, though.

I've got three models, Client, Site, and Contact.  Sites are physical locations that belong to a client, and a client can have many sites.  Contacts are people that belong to one or more sites.  Thus, a client can have many contacts through sites.

**Clients:**

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :sites, -> { where(:sites => {:deleted => false}).order(:name => :asc) }, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :contacts, -> { order(:lastname => :asc) }, :through => :sites

end
```

**Sites:**

```
class Site < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :client
  has_and_belongs_to_many :contacts

end
```

**Contacts:**

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :sites

end
```

The problem is that when I use `Client.find(1).contacts`, I get a `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid` exception:

> Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'contacts.name' in 'order clause': SELECT `contacts`.* FROM `contacts` INNER JOIN `contacts_sites` ON `contacts`.`id` = `contacts_sites`.`contact_id` INNER JOIN `sites` ON `contacts_sites`.`site_id` = `sites`.`id` WHERE `sites`.`client_id` = 5 AND `sites`.`deleted` = 0  ORDER BY `contacts`.`lastname` ASC, `contacts`.`name` ASC

There's the problem: I have no idea where the `` ORDER BY ... `contacts`.`name` ASC `` is coming from.  The Contacts table does not have a name column, but Rails is trying to sort with it and I don't know where it's coming from or how to remove it.  The `` ORDER BY `contacts`.`lastname` ASC `` is easy; it comes from the Client model.

These relationships have worked flawlessly in 3.2, but now throw this exception in 4.0.

**UPDATE:**
It's been pointed out that the extra `` ORDER BY ... `contacts`.`name` ASC `` is coming from the first `has_many` in the Clients model.  However, the intention there was to sort the Sites, not the Contacts.  I tried changing it to `.order('sites.name' => :asc)` and SQL complained about there being no column named `sites.sites.name`.  So, it appears that when using `:through =>` with `has_many`, the order clause gets mangled.

I tried removing the `.order()` and using `default_scope -> { order(:name => :asc) }` in the Sites model, but got exactly the same error as originally reported.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution is simple.  Instead of using `.order(:column_name => :asc)`, I changed it to `.order('column_name ASC')` and the error went away, yielding the expected result.  I originally had the latter, but was implementing the former as part of my Rails 3 -> 4 upgrade, and saw such convention in RailsCasts and other documentation.

This is also necessary when using `.joins()` and ordering by joined table columns, as I later found.  This makes sense, because the association uses joins as well.

Answer (score 1):

You must be tired, right there in your second line (`Client` model), you have **`order(:name=> :asc)`**, it should be:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :sites, -> { where(:sites => {:deleted => false}).order(:lastname => :asc) }, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :contacts, -> { order(:lastname => :asc) }, :through => :sites

end
```

Comment: Not OP, but I assumed that order was referring to the sites table, which would have a name column (but not a last name column).

Comment: Holy cow, you're right.  I took out that `.order()`, and the query worked.  But, the intention was to sort the Sites, not the Contacts., as Eric correctly assessed.  As a test, I changed it to `.order('sites.name' => :asc)` and a new exception was thrown, complaining about 'sites.sites.name' not existing.  So, either way, the `.order()` is broken here.

Comment: Weird, you are right @EricPalace, I assumed *from heart* that it was referring to `Client`. Last time I had to order a similar list I ended up using `:conditions => ["joined_table.some_column...` for this reason